# multiple ScrollView not working on xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Multiple ScrollView is not working on my content page Xamarin forms.so how to solve this?
i added two scrollviiew in my content page,but the second one is not scrolling.

Comment: Without seeing your XAML (or C# code) it's hard to tell what went wrong, even more since the problem description is kind of unclear. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: This should work Horizontally/Vertically on Android, issue is reported here:https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9315

Answer (score -1):

Do not put a ListView inside a ScrollView.

Avoid placing a ListView inside a ScrollView for the following reasons:

- The ListView implements its own scrolling.
- The ListView will not receive any gestures, as they will be handled
  by the parent ScrollView.
- The ListView can present a customized header and footer that scrolls
  with the elements of the list, potentially offering the functionality
  that the ScrollView was used for. For more information see Headers
  and Footers.

If you need more ListView on some Page you should use one ListView with Group.